# What does "straightforward UF" refer to in an algorithm description?

Tags: algorithm, facebook, puzzle

I've come across the term "straightforward uf" to describe the solution (algorithm ?) to the following facebook engineering puzzle: [liarliar](http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php?puzzle_id=20).  Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union-find perhaps? 
http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Union_Find